# How to redirect http traffic to https with spring boot 2.3.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, https

Good afternoon, I am working with spring boot and already implement http safe mode (https), but I need to know how to redirect http requests to https, and if it is necessary to specify a particular safe port like 443, or I can do it with any port. At the moment I use ports 8080 8443

My class

Main Class

```
package com.prueba.https;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PruebaHttpsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PruebaHttpsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Request Class

```
package com.prueba.http.request;

public class PruebaRequest {

    public String nombre;

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

}
```

Response Class

```
package com.prueba.https.response;

public class PruebaResponse {

    public String saludo;

    public String getSaludo() {
        return saludo;
    }

    public void setSaludo(String saludo) {
        this.saludo = saludo;
    }


}
```

Controller Class

```
package com.prueba.https.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.prueba.http.request.PruebaRequest;
import com.prueba.https.response.PruebaResponse;

@RestController
public class PruebaController {


    @PostMapping(value = "/PruebaHTTPS") 
    public Object PruebaController(@RequestBody PruebaRequest req) {
        PruebaResponse res = new PruebaResponse();
        res.setSaludo("Hola " +req.getNombre());
        return res;

    }

}
```

application properties

```
server.port=8443

server.ssl.key-store = classpath:keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password = pass
server.ssl.keyStoreType = PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias = tomcat
```

pom xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.prueba.https</groupId>
    <artifactId>PruebaHTTPS</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>PruebaHTTPS</name>
    <description>Pruebas HTTPS</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Structure of my project

[image]

Conexion HTTPS

[image]

Conexion HTTP

[image]

**UPDATE**

Use the following code that works for my version of spring, however it gives me error with http requests:

```
package com.prueba.https;
import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.SecurityCollection;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.SecurityConstraint;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@ComponentScan
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class WebsocketSourceConfiguration {

      @Bean
      public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new  TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
          @Override
          protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
            securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
            SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
            collection.addPattern("/*");
            securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
            context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
          }
        };
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(getHttpConnector());
        return tomcat;
      }

      private Connector getHttpConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(8080);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort(8443);
        return connector;
      }



}
```

HTTPS (8443)

[image]

HTTP(8443)

[image]

HTTP(8080)

[image]

Why can't I point to http: 8443 and redirect me to https?

Answer (score 1):

To redirect your `HTTP` request to `HTTPS` requests you need add below configurations :

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
  TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
      @Override
      protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
        SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
        securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
        SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
        collection.addPattern("/*");
        securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
        context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
      }
    };

  tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());
  return tomcat;
}

private Connector redirectConnector() {
  Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
  connector.setScheme("http");
  connector.setPort(8080);
  connector.setSecure(false);
  connector.setRedirectPort(8443);
  return connector;
}
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Update my answer with the help of yours, however an error occurs with the port. Do you know what it could be?

Comment: Put 8080 in http set port in redirect connect() line no 3.

Comment: Update my approach. Why can't I point to http: 8443 and redirect me to https? http: 8080 also gives me an error.